# Restart Java RMI registry on same or different port on Windows only after timeout

Tags: java, rmi

I have an RMI server which publishes an object like so:

```
int port = ....;
String name = "...";
Remote server = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(someobject, port+1);
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
registry.rebind(name, server);
log.info("created service name "+name+", on port "+(port+1)
         +" in registry on port "+port);
```

When I stop the program and just rerun it, it logs that it has created everything, but then immediately exits, likely due to the rmi server thread exiting (the last non-daemon). I registered a `defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, but get nothing logged from it. Only after a minute or so I am able to restart the program without it immediately exiting.

If I would always use the same port, this would only half surprise me, because I know that ports may be blocked a little while after their last use. But the behavior is the same even if I use a different port (+100 or so) each time.

Any ideas why this happens and how to possible prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the result of `createRegistry()` into a static variable. Otherwise it is liable to be garbage-collected.

Comment: Once you know it its kind of logical, yet I find it still weird to have a server shutdown depend on whether the GC comes along or not. Must be the Java 1.1 heritage, I guess.

Comment: Nothing to do with 'the Java 1.1 heritage' whatsoever. An object gets garbage-collected => it ceases to be, whether it's a POJO, an exported remote object, the RMI Registry, ...

Comment: What I mean is that an implicit server shutdown by GC looks like an idea from Java 1.1 times. But it may not have been intentional. Today I would think one would provide an explicit shutdown method, which in itself already prompts a user of the server object to keep a reference around.

Comment: I don't understand what you even mean by 'Java 1.1 heritage', unless you just mean 'backwards compatibility'. Distributed Garbage Collection was certainly intentional, and a shutdown method is provided: `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject()`